# Passing twig code into a twig template and rendering it

Tags: symfony, twig

So I have a twig template that's basically empty, and the application generates some twig code and passes this as a variable into a twig template, like this:

```
return $this->render('blank.html.twig', [
    'twig' => $this->generateTwig()
]);
```

blank.html.twig looks like this:

```
{{ twig }}
```

But when the template is rendered it just has un-rendered twig code inside, like this:

```
{% extends 'base.html.twig' %} {% block content %} <h1>{{ 'app-name'|trans }}...
```

How do you render the injected twig code in this example?

Doing a `file_put_contents('blank', $this->generateTwig())` works, but this defeats the purpose of using templates.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can solve this two ways. Either you pre-render `$this->generateTwig()`'s output and inject (the HTML) into the `blank.html.twig` template (untested pseudo):

```php
$template = $this->get('twig')->createTemplate($this->generateTwig());
$twig = $template->render();

return $this->render('blank.html.twig', [
    'twig' => $twig,
]);
```

The downside of this approach is that you have to call `{{ twig|raw }}` in `blank.html.twig`, otherwise Twig will escape the HTML. Also: it feels a bit weird to pre-render a twig template before feeding it to Twig (again).

The other approach is that you load the template inside of your `blank.html.twig` template:

```
{{ include(template_from_string(twig)) }}
```

The `template_from_string` function is part of the `StringLoaderExtension`.

Docs here: https://twig.symfony.com/doc/3.x/recipes.html#loading-a-template-from-a-string

---

Edit: Thinking of it, a third approach could be even simpler if `blank.html.twig` is really just a file that outputs `{{ twig }}`:

```php
$template = $this->get('twig')->createTemplate($this->generateTwig());
return $template->render();
```

Comment: Thanks very much for the details there! You have to add this to config/services.yaml for the template_from_string option to work and it's by far the easiest option: app.twig.extension.loader: class: Twig\Extension\StringLoaderExtension tags: - { name: 'twig.extension' }